# Set up SQL Server connection in Dbvisualizer on Mac

Tags: sql, sql-server, macos, dbvisualizer

I am trying to set up an SQL server connection in db visualiser on mac but i am getting the error "cannot connect to port 1433". I have tried to connect to the port through the terminal but i get the exact same message.

Can anyone advise me on how to set this up? i am a total noob[image]

[image]

Comment: You're pointing to localhost, is the SQLServer really running on your Mac??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the database really running on the same Mac as DbVisualizer? If so, is it configured to accept TCP/IP connections on localhost (127.1.1.1) on port 1433? As I recall, SQL Server does not accept TCP/IP connections by default, and you need to enable it explicitly for each network interface.

Best Regards,
Hans